# Installing digital certificate on Android 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean)

Tags: android, encryption, certificate

I had created an app which would internally generate key pair and use the same to encrypt/decrypt some sample data.

Now my requirement is to use the key pair from an installed certificate on the device to encrypt/decrypt.

To try this I had installed a test certificate which I downloaded from some site. When I installed the certificate, I got message saying that certificate was installed successfully. But I am unable to find that certificate in 
*Settings→Security→Trusted credentials→System/User*.

I don't know whether the certificate really got installed or not.
So I would like to know what is the correct procedure to install a digital certificate on an Android device with 4.1.2 android OS.

Comment: VK - " I got message saying that certificate was installed successfully." Whait until you try and delete it - you have to delete the entire store (no crap, how's that for a security usability bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I would like to know what is the correct procedure to install a digital certificate on an Android device with 4.1.2 android OS

From Android Help Center, [Working with Certificates](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2844832?hl=en):

**Install client & CA certificates**

To install a certificate from your device's internal storage:

> 1. Copy the certificate or key store from your computer to the root of your device's internal storage (that is, not in a folder).
> 2. Go to Settings > Personal > Security > Credential storage > Install from storage.
> 3. Touch the filename of the certificate or keystore to install. Only certificates that you haven't already installed are displayed.
> 4. If prompted, enter the key store password and touch OK.
> 5. Enter a name for the certificate and choose either VPN and apps or Wi-Fi in the credential use menu, and touch OK.

**Work with CA certificates**

> 1. Touch Settings > Personal > Security > Credential storage > Trusted credentials. The trusted credentials screen has two tabs:
>
>    System displays certificate authority (CA) certificates that are
>      permanently installed in the ROM of your phone.
>
>    User displays any CA certificates that you have installed yourself,
>      for example in the process of installing a client certificate.
> 2. To examine the details of CA certificate, touch its name. A scrolling screen displays the details.
> 3. To remove or disable a CA certificate, scroll down to the bottom of the details screen and touch either Disable for system certificates or
>      Remove for user certificates.
>
>    When you disable a system CA certificate, the button at the bottom of
>      its details screen changes to Enable, so you can enable the
>      certificate again if necessary. When you remove a user-installed CA
>      certificate, it is gone permanently and must be re-installed if you
>      want it back.
> 4. In the confirmation dialog that appears, touch OK.